# Invoke specific menu from the sim toolkit menu using an app

Tags: android, mobile, sim-card

How to make a shortcut or an app for android that we can put on the homescreen and invoke a specific menu from the sim toolkit menu? We need to go directly to a menu from the operator sim menu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically control another app unless the target app has exposed some form of API to explicitly allow it.